# redirect all http POST request to specific instance in sharded system

Tags: mongodb, rest, http, proxy, haproxy

I have a system with multiple machines part of mongo sharded cluster. There is REST api to access the database and has GET POST methods to do so.
There is ha-proxy to load balance the HTTP requests across these machines.

In order to boost performance i am planning to tweak the behavior in such a way that all the POST REST requests (which are comparatively less in number) to PRIMARY instance and all the GET request getting load balanced through ha-proxy.

I tried various configuration schemes but i am not able to understand how to expose the POST logic to ha-proxy.

Current setup is as follows

CLIENT Machine - a simulator to generate REST requests
Multiple Server machines part of mongo sharded cluster
A machine running ha-proxy

this is my ha-proxy configuration

```
frontend  main *:5000
    bind 10.60.100.100:8080
    default_backend serverpool

backend serverpool
    balance     roundrobin
    mode  tcp
    server      sv1 7.7.7.1:8080 check
    server      sv2 7.7.7.2:8080 check
```

Comment: As you are not showing your HAProxy configuration, it is difficult to speculate exactly what you are trying  to do, but if you simply place that server in its own backend, then the frontend can simply enough be configured with `use_backend my-post-backend-name if METH_POST`.

Comment: do I have to enable mode http to  be able to use if METH_POST?

Comment: Yes, you do.  If you are not using `mode http` then your task is more difficult. Answering your question requires a more thorough view of your configuration.

Comment: quick solution i am thinking of having a dedicated ip:port server for handling POST requests. I will loose transparency though.

    frontend  main2
        bind 10.60.100.101:8080
        default_backend post_serverpool

    backend post_serverpool
        balance     roundrobin
        mode  tcp
        server      sv1 7.7.7.1:8080 check